# How to add two-factor authetntication to ssh?

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam, two-factor

I am trying to add 2FA to sshd using PAM from oathtool package. I want two ways to login to server:

- publickey and 2FA, or
- password and 2FA

So far I managed to add 2FA to publickey authentication, but don't know how to join password with 2FA.

My sshd_config (OpenSSH_6.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014):

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam password,keyboard-interactive:pam
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
```

PAM sshd:

```
auth required pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/users.oath window=30
```

But this config has no sense: when I am trying to login using password+2FA I asked twice for F2A (once as password, second as OATH.

Comment: If you are trying to implement 2FA with a PAM module, the focus needs to be on your `auth` PAM stack. Please provide the list of modules in order. sshd_config isn't really the focus of this.

Comment: As mefju said, we need to see your pam stack.
I have a [howto here](http://www.howtoforge.com/manage-two-factor-authentication-in-your-serverfarm-with-privacyidea), that tells how to use 2FA with yubikey and ssh. It relies on an authentication backend but also gives you an idea of how to configure PAM.